# Android Undirected graph

Tags: android, graph

I'm using an algorithm to take a snapshot from a bluetooth scatternet on Android ([Beddernet](http://code.google.com/p/beddernet/) + [RES Algorithm](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp;jsessionid=DGwfQQ0Qphn6mBzJh7ZfRX6LwmzLgXDnqXP17XNzWJJ8RJyy1y2x!-1188685217?arnumber=6258160&contentType=Conference+Publications)). But I want to plot this snapshot using and undirected graph.

I found some Java libraries to plot it, but they all use applets and Android doesn't support applets. So how can I do it with Android? (I need the snapshot graph on the device not on the computer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for it.

I'm using this app https://github.com/drange/Grapher to implement my graph. I have modified some parameters to adapt to my app. It uses https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht for graph algorithms.